# Can we do parallel processing for readlines and rbind

Tags: r

This is taking very long time as the readlines has to go in loop and individually. Can you please help to parallelize readlines and rbind?

Please feel free to improve this.

The loop has to go through 40,000+ links

Code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
my_data2 <-c()
urls=readLines("InputLinks.csv")

for ( url in urls) {
valid_url <- TRUE
tryCatch({my_data = 
readLines(str_c("http://https://www.google.co.in/search?q=",url,collapse=''))}, error=function(e) valid_url <<- FALSE)
#the above link is just a sample , I will be doing this in my internal website which will look like this - website+URL+other paramaters


if (!valid_url){ 
next}
my_data <- data_frame(document = url, text = my_data)
my_data2<-rbind(my_data2,my_data)
}
my_data<-my_data2
my_data1 <- my_data %>% 
unnest %>% 
unnest_tokens(word, text, strip_numeric = TRUE) %>%  
group_by(document, word) %>% 
summarise(count = n())
```

Comment: Have a look at the read.directory function in Rfast, some alternatives also here https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/5-3-importing-data.html#fast-data-reading. Although I don't know how these work with links.

Comment: Thanks User. I don't see something useful for links here.